# If a client Udp port punches to a server on one port, can I assume it will send from same port if it sends to a different port on the server?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking, udp

Kind hard to explain so here it is step by step:

1. Client sends data to Server via Udp. Client port X to server port 3000.
2. Server uses this communication to set up a UdpClient to listen for this specific client on port 3001 for client port X.
3. Client then sends data as needed on local port X to server port 3001.
4. Everyone is happy.

My question is: Can I assume that if the client is communicating to the server behind a NAT and it [punches a udp port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), that if it communicates to ANOTHER port on the same server that it will use the same port?

[Edit: formatting]

Comment: Where is the hole-punching in the above steps?

Comment: In the first step. When the client sends the Udp data and opens up port X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not assume that. It may happen or it may not happen, it is up to the writers of the software of the NAT firewall the client is punching through.

A complex software may detect that you are talking to the same server but a different port and reuse the outbound port, but simpler software (the kind you would frequently see on home routers) may be "dumber" and just use a new randomized port per connection.